# Ionic App - Adicionar áudio a um ficheiro de vídeo

Tags: angularjs, ionic

Comecei há pouco a desenvolver com Ionic e estou neste momento a tentar fazer uma app com conteúdo multimédia.

Quero adicionar efeitos de som a um audio gravado pelo dispositivo (client side)
O próximo passo será adicionar o áudio resultante a um vídeo.

Tenho duas opções:

- Fazer o merge dos dois audios num único - PREFERIDO
- Fazer play dos dois sincronizado;

Já fiz alguma pesquisa mas não consegui encontrar a solução adequada para o que procuro..

Alguma sugestão?
Obrigado

cli packages:

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.18.0
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.18.0
```

Local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.2
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools: 26.1.1
Node : v6.11.3
npm  : 3.10.10
OS   : Windows 7
```

Comment: Aqui é o stack overflow em portugues man! por favor traduza p/ PT. abraço! Seja bem vindo! :)

Comment: Obrigado!. Já traduzi :)

Comment: Penso que para fundir os dois ficheiros irá necessitar de um plugin para o IONIC, não sei já existe algum mas pode sempre desenvolver um (http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/hybrid/plugins/index.html). O que é que já experimentou para tocar os dois ficheiros sincronizados?